# Want to change from software developer to Software Tester

Tags: tester

I have working as a software developer from last 3.9 years still my coding skills are not up to the mark . I have worked on core java, GWT framework , no-sql databases but still there is missing something.
Few days before a friend suggested to switch to testing as it will be easier for me as I know the basic coding of java and have coded atleast.

1. I want to know how easy/ difficult is to switch the profile?
2. Will the    industry accept it?
3. What Should I do to crack the interview
   for being    a Tester?
4. What all difficulties I will be facing?

Rather than to opt out from job I want to switch the profile.
Please help me!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching into testing from development](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11715/switching-into-testing-from-development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's reason to be optimistic. Quality assurance requires software development skills. Therefore, your skill set isn't separate from the role. What I suggest focusing on is how to supplement your current skill set for a QA position.

Skills to develop:

1) Testing best practices and methodologies (ie test driven development, test life cycle, agile teamwork, etc)

2) Software Testing tools, frameworks, and new technologies. Are you familiar with automation frameworks such as Selenium? Do you know about BDD tools like Cucumber/Gherkin? How about performance testing tools such as JMeter? You should also learn about continuous integration and writing test suites that run in the pipeline.

3) Learn to think about the big picture. If you apply for a position then think about that company's mission and their application. How would you explain what types of tests they need to run and what shape would a comprehensive test suite take to suit their needs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with CaptainKidd and want to mention some points.

- 100% you will deal with a testing documentation, so you can google some examples to be aware. Search for standards like IEEE, ISO [link](https://www.coleyconsulting.co.uk/IEEE829.htm).
- You can start a preparation to pass through certification program for QAs. For example ISTQB [Link](https://www.istqb.org/downloads/send/2-foundation-level-documents/3-foundation-level-syllabus-2011.html). If you will pass this international exam, then you will be more preferable applicant to any job vacancy.

Here there other files - [docs](https://www.istqb.org/downloads.html).